# How to order data in mysql as given

Tags: mysql, mariadb

How to Sort this table rows such that next row pid isequal to prev row id

| id | name | pid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | row1 | NULL |
| 2 | row2 | 5 |
| 3 | row3 | 2 |
| 4 | row4 | 1 |
| 5 | row5 | 4 |
| 6 | row6 | 3 |

to

| id | name | pid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | row1 | NULL |
| 4 | row4 | 1 |
| 5 | row5 | 4 |
| 2 | row2 | 5 |
| 3 | row3 | 2 |
| 6 | row6 | 3 |

Comment: Use recursive CTE for enumeration. But the data must NOT contain gaps or cycles (which cannot be provided by RDBMS consistency checking subsystem and must be maintained by client logic).

Answer (score 1):

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE
cte AS ( SELECT id, name, pid, 1 level
         FROM table
         WHERE pid IS NULL
       UNION ALL
         SELECT table.id, table.name, table.pid, cte.level + 1
         FROM table
         JOIN cte ON table.pid = cte.id )
SELECT id, name, pid
FROM cte
ORDER BY level
```